# Using gsub for a number between two characters

Tags: awk, split, gsub

I have files as follows:

```
 HNRNPF-human_SRA:SRR4421749_1_ENCFF938GRX.fastq.gz   
 RBFOX2-human_SRA:SRR4421654_1_ENCFF187PBG.fastq.gz                       
 U2AF2-human_SRA:SRR3469570_1_ENCFF158ZML.fastq.gz
 HNRNPK-human_SRA:SRR3469488_2_ENCFF267TVR.fastq.gz   
 RBFOX2-human_SRA:SRR4421654_1_ENCFF588WPC.fastq.gz                       
 U2AF2-human_SRA:SRR3469570_1_ENCFF550GXB.fastq.gz
```

and I would like to relabel them to:

```
 HNRNPF-human_SRA:SRR442174_ENCFF938GRX.fastq.gz   
 RBFOX2-human_SRA:SRR4421654_ENCFF187PBG.fastq.gz                       
 U2AF2-human_SRA:SRR3469570_ENCFF158ZML.fastq.gz
 HNRNPK-human_SRA:SRR3469488_ENCFF267TVR.fastq.gz   
 RBFOX2-human_SRA:SRR4421654_ENCFF588WPC.fastq.gz                       
 U2AF2-human_SRA:SRR3469570_ENCFF550GXB.fastq.gz
```

i.e I remove the number between two '_', I have been trying different commands like gsub and split, but I could only in split command to:

```
  name=U2AF2-human_SRA:SRR3469570_1_ENCFF158ZML.fastq.gz
  echo $name | awk '{split($0, arr, "[__]"); print arr[3]}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**awk** solution. This will do:

```
$ awk -F_ -v OFS=_ '{print $1,$2,$4}' file
HNRNPF-human_SRA:SRR4421749_ENCFF938GRX.fastq.gz
RBFOX2-human_SRA:SRR4421654_ENCFF187PBG.fastq.gz
U2AF2-human_SRA:SRR3469570_ENCFF158ZML.fastq.gz
HNRNPK-human_SRA:SRR3469488_ENCFF267TVR.fastq.gz
RBFOX2-human_SRA:SRR4421654_ENCFF588WPC.fastq.gz
U2AF2-human_SRA:SRR3469570_ENCFF550GXB.fastq.gz
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using `awk`:**

```
$ name="U2AF2-human_SRA:SRR3469570_1_ENCFF158ZML.fastq.gz"
$ awk  'sub(/_[0-9]+_/,"_")' <<<"$name"
U2AF2-human_SRA:SRR3469570_ENCFF158ZML.fastq.gz
```

To save in variable:

```
$ myvar=$(awk  'sub(/_[0-9]+_/,"_")' <<<"$name")
$ echo "$myvar"
```

**OR Bash string substitution**

```
$ name="U2AF2-human_SRA:SRR3469570_1_ENCFF158ZML.fastq.gz"
$ echo "${name/_[0-9]*_/_}"
U2AF2-human_SRA:SRR3469570_ENCFF158ZML.fastq.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove all `_<digit>_` from your strings (replace them with `_`), a simple `sed` substitute will do:

```
$ sed 's/_[0-9]_/_/g' file
```